# Xubuntu Whisker menu custom search action CIFS share - problem

Tags: xubuntu, samba, whisker

I use whisker menu in Xubuntu 16.04 - I attempt to achieve something similar as in Windows for browsing Samba/CIFS shares in network - when typing \ in the searchbar I want to show the share.
What I managed to do so far is:

- Name: Samba
- Pattern: \\
- Action: `exo-open --launch FileManager smb://%s`

When I type i.e. `\\\192.168.1.100` it correctly displays my server shares in the root, but when I try `\\\192.168.1.100\Music` nothing happens and I should be redirected to Music share on 192.168.1.100 server.
Thanks for help,
Tomasz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have figured it out and decided to post an answer here in order someone has trouble too, because the problem was in Whisker Menu itself. My Xubuntu 16.04 came with Whisker Menu 1.5.1 which had a bug - any longer search phrases got truncated in searchbox, thus search terms were incomplete.
I added ppa for Whisker Menu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gottcode/gcppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This upgraded my whiskermenu plugin to 1.5.3 which has this bug fixed and no longer truncates the search term.
The other thing is that in linux smb shares I use smb://192.168.1.100/Music instead of smb://192.168.1.100\Music which was what I initially typed by using my custom action.